# Apple Pay JS, payment Not Complete

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I have done everything needed, I have it running on a verified domain with a SSL certificate, but it still always giving me payment not complete.

```
{
   "epochTimestamp":1631532235832,
   "expiresAt":1631535835832,
   "merchantSessionIdentifier":"S............3",
   "nonce":"6........6",
   "merchantIdentifier":"DA.....2E",
   "domainName":"Company.com",
   "displayName":"Company Name",
   "signature":"4 ...... 0",
   "operationalAnalyticsIdentifier":"B2E",
   "retries":0
}
```

I have checked the epochTimestamp and expiresAt
when I convert the epochTimestamp to time and date I get this date

epochTimestamp -----> Fri, 13 Mar 53671 22:50:32 +0000

CurrentDate -----> 13-Sep-2021 11:33:16

When you remove the last 3 digits from the epochTimestamp it gives the correct time.

In my code it reaches CompleteMerchantValidation then cancels right after that

onPaymentAuthorized and everything else runs before the session even begins

Could it be that what I'm receiving from apple server is incorrect due to having something wrong with the certificates

Comment: Looks like the epochTimeStamp is in milliseconds - which gives a date of 2021-09-13 11:23:55.832

Comment: The problem I had here was how I was sending the domain name I said sending it bas company.com, it should be www.company.com